# SQL script - find highest + 1

Tags: sql-server

I need help. I'm a newbie and I need from you to point me.

I have these tables

```
Table DocVersion
|DocID|ID |Valid      |Description|UserID|
|int  |int|Datetime   |ntext      |int   |
|355  |1  |2021-05-28 |SomeText   |1     | 
|355  |2  |2021-05-28 |SomeText   |1     |
|355  |3  |2021-05-28 |SomeText   |1     |

Table DocVersionLang
|DocID|Version|Language|Text      |Change|TextShort|
|int  |int    |int     |ntext     |ntext |nvarchar |
|355  |1      |10      |SomeText  |''    |SomeText |
|355  |2      |10      |SomeText  |''    |SomeText |
|355  |3      |10      |SomeText  |''    |SomeText |
```

I want to find highest number in ID column in DocVersion table according to DocID and create a same record/row with higher (+1) ID in DocVersion.

If it possible at the same time create a new record according to Docversion.ID=DocVersionLang.Version and Docversion.DocID=DocVersionLang.DocID. (These two steps could be separately and i think it could be better, becase what will be change in DocVersionLang it will be only version and Text or Textshort)

I dont know after this Select max(ID) From DocVersion where DocID=XX,how to write - do a copy of previous row and ID+1 and then what to use - inner join and insert?

Desire reults

```
Table DocVersion
|DocID|ID |Valid      |Description|UserID|
|int  |int|Datetime   |ntext      |int   |
|355  |1  |2019-05-27 |SomeText   |1     | 
|355  |2  |2019-05-27 |SomeText   |1     |
|355  |3  |2019-05-27 |SomeText   |1     |
|355  |4  |ActualTime |SameText   |1     | - same data as previous row but ID++
           (GetDate())                       (and valid column change to actual 
                                             date)

Table DocVersionLang
|DocID|Version|Language|Text         |Change|TextShort  |     ID++ and Text or
|int  |int    |int     |ntext        |ntext |nvarchar   |     TextShort Updated
|355  |1      |10      |SomeText     |''    |SomeText   |
|355  |2      |10      |SomeText     |''    |SomeText   |
|355  |3      |10      |SomeText     |''    |SomeText   |
|355  |4      |10      |UpdatetText  |''    |UpdatedText|
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample data and desire results?

Comment: Ntext? NO NO NO NO NO - that datatype has been deprecated for almost 20 years!

Comment: @MarkoIvkovic added